# Discord.js - Delete all channel by running Discord-Bot without a command

Tags: discord.js, bots, channel

Hey i need for a project a tool to delete all channsl on a Discordserver via a Discord.js Bot.
i got one with handlers and this is my "event code" but dosent work.

Discord.js v14

```
const client = require("../../index");

module.exports = {
  name: "blacksheep"
};
      
client.on("ready", () => {
var server = Client.guilds.get('1045245227264397382'); 
for (var i = 0; i < server.channels.array().length; i++) {
    server.channels.array()[i].delete();
}})
```

i dont find the right way to get it worked. thx <3

Then i start the bot all Channels should be deletet without any command.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include error messages or what the results of running this code was for us to actually help you, but for now I'm going to assume that everything in your bot and bot event handlers is working except for the last three lines that loop through the channels and delete them. If that's the case, then you just need to change those lines to something like this (replace your for-loop block with this):

```js
server.channels.cache.forEach((channel) => {
    channel.delete();
});
```

This accesses the [server's channel cache](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=cache), which is a collection, and so it uses the collection's [forEach](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection?scrollTo=forEach) function to loop through all the channels, and then calls each of the channels' `delete()` functions to delete them.

Note that you may experience severe ratelimiting when doing this, because Discord has heavy ratelimits on requests to server channels.